# Change printer setting programmatically while printing using IP address

Tags: c#

Change printer setting like Print both sides and fit to a page, programmatically while printing using IP address. Currently using socket connection to print, as we dont have printers installed. If there is any other alternative, please suggest.

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
client.Connect("11.11.11.111", 9100); 
byte[] fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine("Random_Path", "FileName"));

Stream s = client.GetStream();
s.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
client.Close();
```

Comment: Hi, in `C#` there is a library called [`System.Drawing.Printing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing). You can use this library to control the printer settings. But i'm not sure you can connect to remote printer with.

Comment: According to online material, found that System.Drawing.Printing is helpful when we have printers installed and that we are sending docs to printer using printer names. So that did not help